# Expose Drupal nodes content throught soap

Tags: nodes

I'd like to build a SOAP server with Drupal but I have some problems.
I've installed the [soap server](https://www.drupal.org/project/soap_server) module (and i'm scared because of the beta status since 2011 ...), and the [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module.
I've created a resource and checked "node" with "api" as endpoint.

With a SOAP client, when I get http://localhost/api?wsdl, I get information but nothing about node management. I only get methods to manage system and user.
In addition, I've managed policies to give full access on node, services and SOAP server to all users.

Did I miss something?

Comment: I have the same problem. There is hardly any documentation on SOAP server out there and I can't find my way around. Which SOAP client are you using? Did you find a way to make it work?